# Use of a private constructor

Tags: java, oop

I'm a begginer programmer for Android and I found some code over the internet and I couldn't get what this "Class not meant to be instantiated" means?! Also what's the use of it. I would be very happy if somebody could help here.

```
public class Settings
{
    //some code
    private Settings() {} // Class not meant to be instantiated
    //some code
}
```

Comment: Go through singleton Design pattern - one of the use case of having private constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a private constructor. This means that outside classes cannot create new instances using the default constructor.

### A little more info

All `Objects` in `Java` have a *default constructor*:

```
public MyObject() {}
```

That is how you can have this class:

```
public class MyObject{}
```

and still be able to call:

```
MyObject mObj = new MyObject();
```

### Private Constructors

Sometimes a developer may not want this default constructor to be visible. Adding any other constructor will nullify this constructor. This can either be a declared constructor with empty parameters (with any of the visibility modifiers) or it can be a different constructor all together.

In the case above, it is likely that one of the following models is followed:

1. The Settings object is instantiated within the Settings class, and is where all the code is run (a common model for `Java` - where such a class would also contain a `static main(String[] args)` method).
2. The Settings object has other, public constructors.
3. The Settings object is a `Singleton`, whereby one `static` instance of the Settings Object is provided to Objects through an accessor method. For example:

---

```
public class MyObject {
    private static MyObject instance;
    private MyObject(){}//overrides the default constructor
    public static MyObject sharedMyObject() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new MyObject();//calls the private constructor
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: "All `Objects` in `Java` have a *default constructor*" - That is not true. The Java compiler will only add a default constructor if you don't provide any constructors at all.

Comment: @Jesper, this is explained further down in the question.

Answer (score 8):

The constructor is private so only the class itself can create instances. There are several reasons for doing this. A couple off the top of my head...

1. The class is a "utility" class that only contains static methods and so instantiating it would make no sense. As the class is commented "Class not meant to be instantiated" I guess this is the most likely reason.
2. The class itself controls its own lifecycle and provides methods for creating instances. For example if the class is a lazy singleton it might provide a method that creates an instance when first called and return this instance on subsequent calls.

Answer (score 3):

This inner construct

```
private Settings() {}
```

is a constructor for `Settings` instances. Since it is private, nobody can access it (outside of the class itself) and therefore no instances can be created.

Comment: No strictly true - the class itself can create instances. No instances can be created outside of the class.

Comment: Here at SO, we say thanks by upvoting or accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is private so its not meant to be called by anything outside of the class

Answer (score 1):

It's not a nested class, it's a constructor. A private constructor means that you can't construct instances of this class from outside, like this:

```
Settings s = new Settings(); //Compilation error! :(
```

Now, if a class can't be instantiated, what could it be for? The most likely reason for this is that the class would return instances of itself from a static method, probably as a singleton. The settings are normally global to the program, so a singleton pattern really fits here. So there would be a static method that goes kind of like this

```
static private TheOnlySettings = null;

static public getSettings()
{
    if(TheOnlySettings == null)
        TheOnlySettings = new Settings(); //Legal, since it's inside the Settings class
    return TheOnlySettings;
}
```

See if that's indeed the case.

Answer (score 0):

As other have mentioned, a class having private constructors cannot be instantiated from outside the class. A static method can be used in this case.

```
class Demo
{

    private Demo()
    {
    }

 static void createObjects()
    {
       Demo o = new Demo();
    }

}

class Test
{
   public static void main (String ...ar)
{
    Demo.createObjects();
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

We can have private constructor . Below program depicts the use of private constructor with a static function

```
class PrivateConstructor {
    private:
    PrivateConstructor(){
        cout << "constructor called" << endl;
    }
public:
    static void display() {
        PrivateConstructor();
    }
};
int main() {
    PrivateConstructor::display();
}
```

Comment: The use of private constructors is to serve singleton classes. A singleton class is one that limits the number of objects created to one. Using a private constructor we can ensure that no more than one object can be created at a time. By providing a private constructor you prevent class instances from being created in any place other than this very class.